# Array is listen only once on all lines

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

i have a problem with sql/pdo, i need an array list with servers like this:

```
$servers = array(
    'server 1' => array('quake3', '194.109.69.61'),
    'server 2' => array('cssource', '194.109.69.51', 27015),
    'server 3' => array('bf2142', '194.109.69.21'),     
    'server 4' => array('ts3', 'voice.planetteamspeak.com')
);
```

I need to get all informations from mysql, where is 'server 1' 'quake3' '194.109.69.61' with $row[1], i used like this:

```
foreach($result as $row) {
    $servers = array(
        'server 1' => array('cs', $row[9], $row[10])
    );
}
```

But show only the same result on all lines.

Comment: Can you show a clearer sample expected output?

Comment: Yes, here is what i get.... ip-s different but the result is the same... http://i68.tinypic.com/30lykie.jpg

Comment: You need to get all information from MySQL? Then show us the table structure and the query, and TELL us what the probelms is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You re-assign same array (**override data**) into `$servers` in each iteration - you better append each row to the result array.

Consider the following:

```
foreach($result as $k => $row) {
    $key = 'server ' . $k; // as "server 1", "server 2" etc...
    $servers[$key] = array('cs', $row[9], $row[10]);
}
```

Now you can see your result in `$servers`

**Edited**

If you want each player to be in new line insert the `<td>` in the nested for-loop as:

```
foreach($result as $row) { 
    foreach ($results as $r) { 
        echo "<tr><td align='center'>$row[17]</td><td align='left'>$row[1]</td><td align='center'>$row[9]:$row[10]</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>".$r['num_players']."/".$r['max_players']."</td>"; echo "<td align='center'>".$r['map']."</td></tr>"; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yes is working now, one last thing is i get all results side-by-side not how they must be one per line. For example: https://ibb.co/r7GS0f1

Comment: @TatuEugen what do you mean side-by-side? I saw the image - how is the `$servers` array look like? (it is hard to give you the desire structure without having access to the actual data...)

Comment: `foreach($result as $k => $row) {
    $key = 'server' . $k; // as "server 1", "server 2" etc...
    $servers[$key] = array('cs', $row[9], $row[10]);
}

foreach($result as $row) {
echo "<tr><td align='center'>$row[17]</td><td align='left'>$row[1]</td><td align='center'>$row[9]:$row[10]</td>";
foreach ($results as $r) {
echo "<td align='center'>".$r['num_players']."/".$r['max_players']."</td>";
echo "<td align='center'>".$r['map']."</td></tr>";
}
 }`

Comment: @TatuEugen It is not so clear - but I think I manged to understand - edited my post. If it helps you you may consider marking it as "accepted" so other may use it

Comment: Thank you, i do it something, but still i cannot combine rows from sql with rows from server details, if i use two foreach i get double results, with one foreach i get something like: https://ibb.co/jy00kvj  , but i must choose one, sql or live details

Comment: It sound like UI issue - I recommend you open a new question with more detailed explanation of your current code and output and a desire one

Answer (score 0):

You're not clear where the "server name" (e.g. 'server 1') or "game type" (e.g. 'cs') comes from.

However, some things are clear. You are overwriting the `$servers` array with each new row.

Something like this would give better results:

```
$servers = array(); // or []
foreach ($result as $n => $row) {
    $servers['server ' . ($n+1)] = array('cs', $row[9], $row[10]);
}
```

That would get you an array of servers. They'll all be of type 'cs'.  I'd assume the game type is another one of your columns though...

It might be clearer to return an associative array, so you can use column names rather than index numbers.  e.g.

```
$servers = array(); // or []
foreach ($result as $n => $row) {
    $servers['server ' . ($n+1)] = array($row['game'], $row['ip'], $row['port']);
}
```

Comment: CS and Server 1 is just there, not come from anywhere, just the row[1] comes from sql db. Thank you!